Javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException Ldap: error code 53 - 00002035
please help me to resolve this issue. I am new to Ldap security groups.
My requirement : I want to add the uses to my Ldap security group through java code.
Error : Javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException
Ldap: error code 53 - 00002035: LdapErr: DSID-0C09105E, comment : Operation not allowed through GC port, data 0, v3839]
I am expecting that my java code will add the user to Ldap security group.

As the error message says:

Operation not allowed through GC port

Active Directory domain controllers provide two LDAP services: a read-write service on the standard LDAP ports (389/636) which contains the current domain's data, and a read-only "Global Catalog" service on alternate ports (3268/3269) which contains minimal replicated data from the entire forest.
To perform any changes to the directory, as the error message states, you must connect to the regular r/w LDAP service on ports 389 or 636 instead.
